# How can I loop through a determinated range of rows?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am stuck with the beginning of my analysis. Perhaps the question could be stupid, but I would like to request your help for some tips. 
I have a dataframe with several variables; and each variable has 10 observations. My doubt is how can I estimate for each variable the max of the first 5 observations, and the max of the following 5 observations.

This is an example of my code:

```
    for (i in 1:length(ncols)){
 max.value <- max(var1)
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Here goes and example with the dataset "iris" from vegan's package. In this case, I would like to estimate the max value of each variable for group of 50 observations. Notice that in this dataset, each group of 50 variables correspond with a one different level of the variable species.

`library(vegan)
data("iris")

data.test <- iris[,1:4]
for (i in 1:ncol(data.test)){
  print (i)
  maxval <- max(i)
 
}`

thank you!

Comment: Do you need `aggregate(cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, iris, max)` ?

Comment: I think you're real question is how to find a maximum per group?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The function aggregate works nicely :)

Yes, my real question is how to find a max per group, but, without the group per se... I mean, I have not a variable group in my dataset, but I know a priori how many observations are included in each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Add running ID to check results if you want to
mtcars$ID <- seq.int(nrow(mtcars))

# Make index to separate data 50/50
ind <- seq_len(0.5*nrow(mtcars))

# Make two DFs "first..." and "second..."
firstpart <- mtcars[ind, ]
secondpart <- mtcars[-ind, ]

# Look at the results
View(firstpart)
View(secondpart)

# do your stuff to data
```